# why I can't download csv filetype,but PDF filetype success,is it the downloaded CSV file has been intercepted?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

As the title says,After I login by selenium,I try use mouse to click download botton,when I choose CSV filetype,I didn't see it at download path,but when I choose PDF filetype,I can see it.It should have nothing to do with my code, because I only use selenium to simulate logging in, and everything after logging in is done manually.is it the downloaded CSV file has been intercepted? what can I do about it?
Help me,please!

Comment: Your question is not clear and it's difficult to understand what you are asking.

Comment: This seems like an issue with the website you are using that is unrelated to selenium, but it's not entirely clear from what you've shared.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ambiguous statement . Let me rephrase my question , I want to use selenium to download a CSV file from the website , after executing my code successfully ,  I didn't see it at download path when I choose export file as csv ,.Interesting , I can see it at download path when I choose export filetype as PDF. It  seems like csv file was intercepted ,  It should be noted that  I can download the csv file      
 successful when I didn't use selenium to login this website . Have I made my question clear? I'm a novice Programer,can you help me?@vitaliis

Comment: I'm sorry for my ambiguous statement . Let me rephrase my question , I want to use selenium to download a CSV file from the website , after executing my code successfully ,  I didn't see it at download path when I choose export file as csv ,.Interesting , I can see it at download path when I choose export filetype as PDF. It  seems like csv file was intercepted ,  It should be noted that  I can download the csv file      
 successful when I didn't use selenium to login this website . Have I made my question clear? I'm a novice Programer,can you help me?@C.Peck